# How could I add a comma between strings?

Tags: string

I want to add only a comma between KimLee from reslt.

This is function I made

```
def reg_student(self,s2):
    global data
    data=data + s2.name
    self.student=data
```

These are the function calls

```
prof1.reg_student(stu1)
prof1.reg_student(stu2)

print "My students are"%(self.student)
```

Result

```
My students are KimLee
```

Comment: Are you using Python?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
def reg_student(self,s2):
    global data

    if not 'data' in globals():
        data = ""

    data += (", " if data else "") + s2.name
    self.student=data
```